# Data is not updating when CassandraOperations update is used

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am using `CassandraOperations` update method to update `Cassandra` row.

The update operation most of the times is failing. And sometimes few fields are updating and few fields are not.

My usage is as follows:

- Get Mapping object from Cassandra DB using `CassandraOperations` select method
- Update few fields on returned object
- Update modified object to Cassandra DB using `CassandraOperations` update method.

I am using `Cassandra2.1.9`, `spring-data-cassandra1.3.0`, `cassandra-driver-mapping2.2.0-rc3`.

Please provide me any suggestions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info... Which fields are you trying to update? Are they part of primary key? What is the error when update is failing?

Comment: Non primary key fields are not updating and no error has been observed. Through debug I observed exception with following message while filling properties in `BasicPersistentEntity` class.**java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Defaults$NoCodec cannot access its superclass com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec**